# Bootstrap typeahead doesnt work when call async task from service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to play with bootstrap typeahead and angular. When current method was in controller - all worked fine:

```
$scope.getLocation_work = function(val) {
    return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(res){
      var addresses = [];
      angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
        addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
      });
      return addresses;
    });
  };
```

When I tried to put the logic into service, I started get errors:

```
ypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

**in controller**

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
            UtilsFactory.getLocation(val).then(function(res){
                var addresses = [];
                angular.forEach(res, function(item){
                    addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
                });
                return addresses;
            });
        };
```

**Service**

```
app.factory('UtilsFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
                return {
                    getLocation : function(val) {
                          var deferred = $q.defer();
                          var response = $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                params: {
                    address: val,
                    sensor: false
                }
            });

             deferred.resolve(response);
               return deferred.promise;
                }      
       }
  }
]);
```

Do I miss something?

Here is Demo in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VZ69JlKhzbWvm6I68lQA?p=preview)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 problems in your plunker:

(1) For whatever reason you were writing `$http` promise callback differently when called from a controller and differently when a promised was returned from the service. But promise hitting a backend is the same promise with the same results so it should be handled the same:

```
        $scope.getLocation = function(val) {
            return UtilsFactory.getLocation(val).then(function(res){
                var addresses = [];
                angular.forEach(res.data.results, function(item){
                    addresses.push(item.formatted_address);
                });
                return addresses;
            });
        };
```

On top of this you were missing the `return` in the `$scope.getLocation` function!

(2) `$http` already works with promises so there is no need to use `$q` on top of it. You can write your service as simply as:

```
app.factory('UtilsFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getLocation : function(val) {
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
          params: {
            address: val,
            sensor: false
          }
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Finally a fixed plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/hG5iHWfGq3QNAp6J8YSW?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can wrap anything (sync/async) with `deferred` so I generate new promise. Actually I get the list from my service and its populated right but somehow fails to update bootstrap. Again Thanks,

Comment: How about using typeahead-input-formatter="formatLabel($model)" to display the label and save the value for model? Actually I am loading ajax content with label, id pairs of json. I need to show the label, but need to store id in the database.The issue was already reported in [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2160)